# Speed Optimization of Shopify Store

Tags: caching, shopify, pagespeed

I need help with optimizing speed for my shopify store. It loads fine but if I check in Google Pagespeed the stats are 64 / 100 for mobile and 79 / 100 for desktop. I compressed some images, uploaded them to assets but it still picks up the cached version. I tried minifying CSS but no luck. Store link is https://crown-and-clutch.myshopify.com/
1) How can I flush shopify cache to get latest changes?
2) What can I exactly do to increase google page speed score?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Mention how you are calling asset files in your theme.
2. Remove Google map API if you are not using it

Comment: I am calling images like this: <img src="{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name | escape }}" />. I asked shopify support and they said whenever I want to clear cache I have to reach out to them. So cache issue is resolved.

Now, if I try to minify any css file it messes up my site. E.g I minified bootstrap and my store was not responsive any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scores are too generous. 79 for desktop, way too high considering how poorly the page is designed.

Total of 145 files to create one page.
It takes the Browser 9 seconds to render all that crap.

Your biggest issue is 1,114,524 bytes of JavaScript in 45 files.
And the JavaScript is compressed meaning there is likely more then twice as many bytes. FireFox says 3,700,000+ bytes of JS
Probably none of the JavaScript is needed.  For example google maps JS is loading.  Yet no maps on the page.

The transmission speed and configuration of your server is okay.

It's just a horrific design.

Just don't let that 79% lead you to believe your site speed is passable.

You are losing a good percentage of visitors due to slow and jumbled page loads. If you are losing only 10% you'd be lucky.

I could go on but this is an old post and I'm not sure you will even see this.

There is no technical reason this page cannot be designed to load in less than a second and score 99%.

[image]

CSS not good, 70,228 bytes in 10 files.  Most not used. And 669 Errors

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you @Misunderstood on remove unused CSS and JS Cod and it's will improve the loading but you may also implement some others to improve your loading and specially on mobile drives like:

- Make responsive images
- Compress Images
- Preload Web Fonts, JS and CSS
- Make Render-blocking resources load asynchronously
- Combine all JS in one file and minify it to reduce the number of request and page size
- Load only visible by implementing lazy loading technique

I wrote a guide on how to implement this technique in your Shopify theme

[Shopify Speed Optimization — Step-by-Step Guide](https://medium.com/@iliashaddad/shopify-speed-optimization-step-by-step-guide-4afca6423b18)